# convert POJO to JsonNode with POJO fieldnames

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo, jackson-databind

Requirement:

1. collect selected fields from a json file into a POJO(field names do not match)
2. update other non-mapped fields of POJO
3. convert back to jsonNode with POJO fieldnames

Problem:
steps 1 and 2 are fine. When converting POJO back to JsonNode I am unable to get it in POJO field names. Can anyone suggest a way to get this?

below is my code

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPOJO {

@JsonProperty("Firstname")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("Country")
private String nationality;

private String state;

//getters and setters
}
```

logic

```
     ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root =map.readTree(new Main().getResorceFile());
    List<MyPOJO> myList = new ArrayList<MyPOJO>();

    for(JsonNode each : root){
        MyPOJO myPOJO = new MyPOJO();
        myPOJO= map.readValue(each.toString(),MyPOJO.class);
        System.out.println(myPOJO.toString());
        myList.add(myPOJO);
    }
    for(MyPOJO p : myList){
        JsonNode node = map.convertValue(p,JsonNode.class);
        System.out.println((node.toString()));
    }
```

Json file

```
    {
        {
            "Firstname":"Tez",
            "Lastname":"Morris",
            "Country":"US"
        },
        {
            "Firstname":"Kip",
            "Lastname":"Lee",
            "Country":"US"
        },
        {
            "Firstname":"Pam",
            "Lastname":"Carr",
            "Country":"US"
        },
        {
            "Firstname":"lin",
            "Lastname":"Dale",
            "Country":"US"
        }
    }
```

output:

```
    Main{name='Tez', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='Kip', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='Pam', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='lin', nationality='US', state='null'}
    {"state":null,"Firstname":"Tez","Country":"US"}
    {"state":null,"Firstname":"Kip","Country":"US"}
    {"state":null,"Firstname":"Pam","Country":"US"}
    {"state":null,"Firstname":"lin","Country":"US"}
```

expected output

```
    Main{name='Tez', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='Kip', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='Pam', nationality='US', state='null'}
    Main{name='lin', nationality='US', state='null'}
    {"state":null,"name":"Tez","nationality":"US"}
    {"state":null,"name":"Kip","nationality":"US"}
    {"state":null,"name":"Pam","nationality":"US"}
    {"state":null,"name":"lin","nationality":"US"}
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid... these objects in the outer object have no keys. Presumably this should be a list, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put the `@JsonProperty` on getters and setters with different values, like:

```
[…]
private String nationality;

@JsonProperty("nationality")
public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

@JsonProperty("Country")
public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}
[…]
```

The getter performs serialization, the setter deserialization.